# Jersey with embedded Jetty resolving dependency injection in Resource

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I'm having troubles to wire Jersey with Jetty while trying to inject dependencies of my resouce. What I'm doing is:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new MyBinder());
    }
}
```

My binder simplified:

```
public class MyBinder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ManagerImpl.class).to(Manager.class);
        }
   }
```

And my resource simplified:

```
@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    Manager manager;
...
}
```

I tried this to wire all that together:

```
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
ServletContainer jerseyServletContainer = new ServletContainer(new MyApplication());
ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(jerseyServletContainer);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", MyResource.class.getCanonicalName());
servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
servletContextHandler.addServlet(jerseyServletHolder, "/*");

Server server = new Server(threadPool);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(httpPort);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
server.start();
```

However I keep receiving HTTP ERROR: 404

Any ideas how I could get it sorted?

Thanks

Comment: what's your request URL?

Comment: I have a similar project, but it doesn't use the injection you're doing [here](https://github.com/aakture/helloworld) maybe it helps get you going.

Comment: 0.0.0.0:8800/test?some=stuff, however I figured out dropwizard, which basically resolves all my issues, achieving exact the thing I was aiming for. Even integrating Guice for injection. http://www.codingricky.com/dropwizard-and-guice-integration/

Comment: Awesome. I should have recommended that... I've been using dropwizard and guice for a few years and love it. The Metrics library is indispensable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I also made it work without dropwizard and guice. For some reasons Jersey implementation doesn't include GuiceComponentProviderFactory since the version 2.XX. Otherwise it would be possible to do something like this:

```
Injector injector =  Guice.createInjector( new ServletModule() { ...} );
IoCComponentProviderFactory ioc = new GuiceComponentProviderFactory( resourceConfig, injector );
Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createHttpServer( BASE_URI + "services/", resourceConfig, ioc );
```

Since version 2.X they have integrated HK2 IoC framework with a GuiceBirdge, so you would need to mess around with HK2 and Guice:

```
GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(aServiceLocator);
```

So I simply stick to HK2 for the moment having it wired all together in this way:

```
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8800).build();
Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer( baseUri, new MyApplication() );
server.start();
```

My ResourceConfig:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new MyBinder());
        register(MyResource.class);
    }
}
```

So I simply missed to register my resources on top of registering my binder. So in that way I'm not using web.xml at all having nicely embedded jetty server.